# How do I use CTRL-R to cut all the way through an object, not just one face?

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

Can you please tell me if there is a handy shortcut or hotkey using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> or the knife tool to cut ALL the way through an object and not just it's face? I want to make a simple cut to make the tape follow the form of the bottle.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why loop cut (Ctrl+R) doesn't work? I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: If the loop cut will not cut all the way through an object, one thing to look for is nonconforming geometry in the path of the loop cut, that is to say that the loop cut is encountering a trianglular face, an n-gon, or the edge of the geometry..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The knife tool will work in this situation. After pressing <kbd>K</kbd>, hit <kbd>Z</kbd>, which will put it in cut through mode.

[image: cut through]

Comment: Bingo! Knife / Z  was the perfect solution - Thank you.